# Enabling search across multiple html pages

Tags: html, documentation-generation

I have a large number of html pages referencing each other across multiple folders. Is there a way to create a search window that can search through all the pages that are being linked?

If that isn't easily possible but all my html pages were in one unique folder, would there be a way?

Comment: It depends on the system you're building the site in... most things like DreamWeaver / NotePad / Visual Studio / VSCode have a 'Find in files' feature.

Comment: The use case would be for these html pages to be open and searchable from a browser. I'd rather avoid using a find in file feature from a different viewer.

Comment: Well you could run some sort of automation tool or sniffer across your site to index each file there and then check the contents of each, and alert you if the desired keyword is found. But again, that would be complex and slow, whereas it would only take a few seconds to use the `Find in files` feature in any given editor. I can't think of a reason you'd need to do it from a browser; other users wouldn't be able to update the DOM anyway...